# How to get all merged field in a word document by uno open office

Tags: c#, openoffice.org

I am beginner to open office sdk. I need to find out all merge fields          (eg. «FirstName») in a word document.

Can any one suggest a working solution?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post any relevant code.  Also I am not sure I understand what is meant by "finding out" merge fields.  You want to do a merge, or perhaps read through a template and list the names of all of its fields?

Comment: If you are asking about mail merge fields.. these are `TextField`s, covered in `Chapter 7.3.5 of the Developers Guide` in the [AOO] SDK.  I haven't worked with them in a `WORD` document (because I use ODF - Writer format), nor with c# (as I use StarBasic or Python). Andrew's document has examples in StarBasic to access `TextField`s